# Intel CPU targeted DLL on M1/M2 (ARM CPU) workaround for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, x86-64, cpu, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

So I’m working on a Unity project and I recently got a new Mac with the M2 chip. I realized that some of the DLLs I use are targeting intel based CPUs and they don’t work in Unity. I use Rosetta as a workaround for this but unity doesn’t seem to be able to use Rosetta for this.

I do not have access to the source code for the dlls so I can’t recompile them targeting ARM CPU’s. Has anyone here encountered the same issue? Does anyone know of any solution to this issue?

Comment: Rosetta doesn't let you mix & match architectures within a single process.  If you have some x86-64-only stuff, you have to build the whole thing as x86-64 and run it under emulation.  Also, DLLs?  You're running Windows on this hardware?  Since you also said Rosetta, I assume you mean macOS shared libs.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant .dylib files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed the non-apple-silicon version of Unity3d Editor and IDE. Both intel-based versions should work fine. At least it solved the same problem for me on my Macbook Pro with an M1 chip. You can see both intel and apple-silicon versions of the unity editor (the screenshot below was made from my local unity hub)
[image]

Comment: You mean non-*Apple*-silicon version, i.e. x86-64 builds of the project, so it can use x86-64 libraries?  Software isn't made of silicon at all, but all mainstream CPUs are, including M2 and Intel CPUs.

Comment: I mean the non-apple-silicon version of the Unity3d editor. You can choose the version during installation.

Comment: Interesting that the only text in the "tag" is "silicon", but the apple icon is a critical part of it.  You should edit the text of your answer to say "apple silicon" rather than just "silicon", because "apple silicon" is the standard name for M1 / M2 CPUs and AArch64 macOS.  If you want a one-word name for it, call it ARM64 or AArch64, or possibly just ARM.

Comment: I used it as it is called so in the Unity Hub where you can choose the version to install ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: They write "silicon" in text without an Apple icon in front of it somewhere other than that screenshot?  That seems weird.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to solve it for me unfortunately